# programming batch file

Tags: batch-file

How can I programmed batch file at windows xp that it will perform combination of keys? for example: win+L to switch user or other combinations.

Comment: This does *not* belong on superuser - batch files are programming as well, unless you're a programming snob :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo I am the *last* person to banish something onto SU - in fact, I frequently fight with people to keep questions here :) I misunderstood the question, I thought he wants to customize his PC, which is obviously not the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered that a batch file may not be the best approach? The Windows Scripting Host has a "SendKeys" function which can be called from VBScript.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83%28VS.85%29.aspx
- http://www.devguru.com/Technologies/wsh/quickref/wshshell_SendKeys.html

IIRC, WSH can be called from other scripting languages too.

Comment: +1 And if the OP wants, he/she can have a batch file that triggers JScript or VBScript via `cscript.exe`: `cscript.exe /nologo scriptname "keys to send"`, for instance, if the script accepts the keys to send as a string (accessible from `WScript.Arguments`).

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure how easy it is to do this with sending key sequences but just about any action can be done by calling the appropriate executable.

For example,

```
rundll32.exe user32.dll, LockWorkStation
```

will do what <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> normally does.

[This site](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/rundll.php) shows quite a number of possibilities.

Comment: +1. Creating a mechanism that simulates keystrokes would be a huge effort - much easier to call the associated commands.